# What is it called when 2 systems fight to keep their value?

Tags: integration, data

This is probably an easy question, I just can't find an answer (happy to delete or repost in the right spot).

**Scenario**

1. System A updates a record to have value "United States", and syncs the value to System B
2. System B updates the record to have value "USA", and syncs the value to System A
3. Rinse and repeat until end of time

We've used the word "thrashing", but it's a VM memory term.  Is there a better word for this?

Comment: Is System B responding to System A's update, then System A responding to System B's update or are they simply updating the values independently?

Comment: If the updates are in response to the other system's change in each case (except for the starting update against either system) then I'd call this a feedback loop.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've used "thrashing" to describe this situation too.

Comment: System B is responding to System A's update, and "Fixing" the value. They each think "they" know the correct value and are fighting to stay right.  Bi-directional sync.  I like feedback loop, though looking for a better word (if it exists)

Comment: It's also a problem, from what you said, related to data mastery or ownership. Both systems believe they are the owner of this data. You have a data ownership conflict or contention.